# Remove the padding spaces in the `ls` result on macOS

Tags: macos, bash, ls

When I run command `ls` on macOS, it shows the folder names with same length, padding spaces for short folder names:

`jihu@ksm1 Home $ ls
bin      code     devel    opt      personal shared`

While on Linux it looks much better:

`jihu@hqlin1 Home $ ls
bin  code  devel  opt  personal  shared`

Is there any options to remove the padding spaces on macOS? On both system I am using bash.

Comment: Bash doesn't affect the output of external programs, it only starts them.

Comment: Not sure about `ls` on Linux, but what Mac's `'ls` is trying to do is to create "columns" of output.  Run `ls` on a folder with a lot of files, and you'll see how nicely everything lines up.  You're right, it doesn't look good if the spacing only affects one line, but try it on a big folder and I think you'll like it.  Perhaps Linux `ls` is smart enough to do the column-thing if there's more than one row, but skip if there's only one row?

Comment: @jimtut actually I think it's because GNU `ls` is willing to use spaces (instead of and not only tabs) when achieving columnar output (see https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c#L4958 ) whereas BSD `ls` will only ever use tabs. Since tabs are typically bigger than a space the maximum number of columns that can be fitted on to one row with BSD `ls` is less...

Answer (score 3):

From looking at the [`man ls` on macOS](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Darwin+8.0.1%2Fppc&arch=default&format=html) you might like the `-m` option that just separates entries with commas or the `-1` option if you are OK with each entry on a new line. I suppose you could also do `ls -C | tr -s "\t" " "` but that feels a bit clunky...

An extreme solution might be to use something like Homebrew to install `coreutils` and that would give you access to `gls` (GNU `ls` but with a different name to avoid conflicts) which comes from the same upstream as the `ls` you are using on Linux.